# SQL Server query no longer slow after query char or parameter type change

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following query :

```
SELECT
  A.id,
  NEWID() as id,
  RTRIM(LTRIM(A.label)) as label
FROM (
SELECT
  a.id_aff as id,
  p.nom as label
FROM
  A a inner join
  P p on p.id_aff = a.id_aff INNER JOIN
  L l on l.id_aff = a.id_aff INNER JOIN
  PL pl on pl.id_lien = l.id_lien AND pl.id_prog = p.id_prog INNER JOIN
  S s on s.id_prog = p.id_prog
where
  s.id_pub = :idPub and l.id_type = :idType and
  s.active = 1 and s.valid = 1
UNION
SELECT
  a.id_aff as id,
  p.nom as label
FROM
  A a inner join
  P p on p.id_aff = a.id_aff INNER JOIN
  L l on l.id_aff = a.id_aff INNER JOIN
  S s on s.id_prog = p.id_prog INNER JOIN
  SL sl on sl.id_lien = l.id_lien AND sl.id_session = p.id_prog
where
  s.id_pub = :idPub and l.id_type = :idType and
  s.active = 1 and s.valid = 1
) A
ORDER BY
 RTRIM(LTRIM(A.label)) ASC
```

Normally the query execution time is approximately 2 - 3 seconds.
Suddenly this query execution time rise to 1 minute - 1 minute and 30 seconds.

This query is executed by hibernate by the following code :

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(QUERY, Select.class);
Integer id = 1;
query.setParameter("id", idAffilie);
query.setParameter("idType", SystemConstant.ID_TYPE);
List<Select> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

I execute the following tests :

**1) Changing the parameter type**

If for example i change the type of id from Integer to String without modifying the query, the query return the same result and the execution the is back to normal (2 - 3 seconds) :

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(QUERY, Select.class);
String id = "1";
query.setParameter("id", idAffilie);
query.setParameter("idType", SystemConstant.ID_TYPE);
List<Select> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

**2) Changing the query formatting**

If i change the query formatting the same result occur the query execution the is back to normal (2 - 3 seconds). In this example, I change the `SELECT` formatting :

```
SELECT A.id, NEWID() as id, RTRIM(LTRIM(A.label)) as label
FROM (
SELECT
  a.id_aff as id,
  p.nom as label
FROM
  A a inner join
  P p on p.id_aff = a.id_aff INNER JOIN
  L l on l.id_aff = a.id_aff INNER JOIN
  PL pl on pl.id_lien = l.id_lien AND pl.id_prog = p.id_prog INNER JOIN
  S s on s.id_prog = p.id_prog
where
  s.id_pub = :idPub and l.id_type = :idType and
  s.active = 1 and s.valid = 1
UNION
SELECT
  a.id_aff as id,
  p.nom as label
FROM
  A a inner join
  P p on p.id_aff = a.id_aff INNER JOIN
  L l on l.id_aff = a.id_aff INNER JOIN
  S s on s.id_prog = p.id_prog INNER JOIN
  SL sl on sl.id_lien = l.id_lien AND sl.id_session = p.id_prog
where
  s.id_pub = :idPub and l.id_type = :idType and
  s.active = 1 and s.valid = 1
) A
ORDER BY
 RTRIM(LTRIM(A.label)) ASC
```

**Question : why changing a parameter or the query formatting makes this query execution time back to the normal ?**

This issue is encountered with a few queries but not all of them.

Cardinalities of tables :

- A : 9000 records
- P : 25000 records
- L : 185000 records
- PL : 736000 records
- S : 600000 records
- SL : 20000 records

SQL Server : Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU3) (KB4538853) - 15.0.4023.6 (X64)

Spring boot : 2.0.9
Spring data JPA : 2.0.14
Hibernate : 5.2.18

Thanks and have a good day.

**EDIT**

SQL server driver maven version : 9.2.1.jre8

Comment: What is the data type of the column being compared to, where you changed the data type of the parameter from an `int` to a `string`? A `varchar`, by any chance?

Comment: @Larnu The column type is `int`. With the slow version of the query i compare `int` to `int`. But if i change to `String`, the query is fast.

Comment: Quite simple: there are two different plans that the compiler comes up with. It generated a bad one and is reusing it, when you change the tiniest bit if the query (even spacing) it recompiles and gets a good plan. This is called [*parameter sniffing*](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/). For better help, please include table and index `CREATE` definitions, and share the two query plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan